# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined in Mongoose 4.0.3

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to add some validators to the mongoose scheme. My model looks like :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Usr = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    email1: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    admin: { type: Boolean },
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    hasCar: { type: Boolean },
    phone: { type: Number }
});

Usr.schema.path('email1').validate(function (value) {
    return /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(value);
}, 'Invalid email');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', Usr);
```

But I'm getting a TypeError :

```
Usr.schema.path('email1').validate(function (value) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Usr` itself is a Schema object. So:

```
Usr.path('email1').validate(function (value) {
    return /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(value);
}, 'Invalid email');
```